# Golang - Converting uint to os.FileMode

Tags: go, casting, type-conversion

I'm trying to get user permissions for a file from the user as a string and convert it into type `os.FileMode`.

So, after I get the permission `"0644"` and convert it, it becomes `644`. I am using this as a parameter to `ioutil.WriteFile`.

This is what I'm doing.

```
data["perm"] = "0644"
tempval, err2 = strconv.ParseUint(data["Perm"], 10, 32)
// tempval is 644
```

I'm not getting the right permissions.

I get `--w----r--` instead of `-rw-r--r--`
I've been trying to find a workaround.

So, how exactly do I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tempval, err2 = strconv.ParseUint(data["Perm"], 10, 32)
```

You're explicitly asking for base 10 here. If you want base 8 (which is the traditional base for unix file modes), then you need to use `8` in the second parameter. Or better, use base `0`, and it'll automatically choose base 8 due to the leading 0. See the docs on `strconv.ParseInt` for how "base 0" works.